# Remove resource item from array when resource item on server is deleted

Tags: angularjs

When I do a delete action on an item from a server resource it doesn't remove the item in the view.

The View:

```
%ul(class="phrases")
  %li(ng-repeat="phrase in phrases")
    %p.id {{phrase.id}}
    %p.content {{phrase.content}}
    %p.author {{phrase.author}}
    %button(ng-click="deletePhrase(phrase.id)") Delete ^
```

The services:

```
 wrmcServices.factory 'Phrase', ($resource) ->
   $resource('api/v1/phrases.json',{},
     query:
       method:'GET'
       params:
         phraseId:'phrases'
       isArray:true
   )

 wrmcServices.factory 'Phrase', ($resource) ->
   $resource('api/v1/phrases/:id.json',{id: "@id"},
     update:
       method:'PUT'
     delete:
       method: 'DELETE'
   )
```

The controller:

```
wrmcControllers.controller 'phrasesCtrl', ($scope, Phrase) ->
  $scope.phrases = Phrase.query()
  $scope.deletePhrase = (phraseId) ->
    Phrase.delete({id: phraseId}, ->
      $scope.phrases.splice(phraseId,1)
    )
```

My temporary fix was to place $scope.phrases = Phrase.query() at the end of the deletePhrase function but I dont like how the page refreshes. Shouldnt angular just remove the item from new view because I am removing it from the array.

Comment: angularj does updates automatically. Btw splice works on index, so i dont think `$scope.phrases.splice(phraseId,1)` this works..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $scope.phrases is an array you should be able to do this

```
ng-click="deletePhrase(phrase.id, $index)"
```

And change the delete method

```
$scope.deletePhrase = (phraseId, index) ->
  Phrase.delete({id: phraseId}, ->
    $scope.phrases.splice(index,1)
  )
```

I'm not sure about the syntax because I'm not used to it. But you get the idea.

Comment: For people in the future like me here an explanation:
`arr.splice(index, count)` deletes `count` elements starting from index `index`. So arr.splice(1,1) would remove one element from index 1 so the second element of the array.